# How to assign drivers and passengers to cars using google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hello I have about 120 employees working on two shifts and living in 4 cities to which they drive with company cars(9 people van, so driver + 8 passengers, the cars do not always have to be full).

I have prepared a sheet with two tabs. On the first I have:

- Name of the empleyee in column A
- City they live in in column B
- Whether they have drivers' license(yes/no) in column C
- Whether they are on vacation(yes/no) in column D

And on another tab I have created a table with a car registration plate(B1) and direction it drives to in cell B2.

I am trying to create a script that will(on button press, one button per car) push the data into D2:D10 based on if:
People are living in the same city AND they are not on vacation AND at least one of them has drivers' license.

I am not sure whether I even have the right idea for that script(or what to use to push the data) because the only script I have ever written was to archive a sheet and clear cells in the original one.

I would like to get some guidance on:

- What I am doing is correct
- How to take the data that will pass the if conditions and put it into the table

[Here is a link to a copy of the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NQ9PrfjoNdcW6F2vjhqW4-u4J_TJttIgRkDK8RzD2qg/edit?usp=sharing)

```
function updateCar1() {
let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
let range = ss.getRange("A2:D61");
let town = ss.getCell("cars!B2");

for(range){
if(ss.getCell("cars!B2")==town && ss.getRange("D2:D61")=="No" && ss.getRange("C2:C61")=="Yes"){

}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Your idea is correct, the remaining issue is how to loop through a range

For this

- first you need to [get the values](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) of the range, since you cannot loop through a range without it
- then you need to loop through the rows of the 2D value range
- for each row, you can access the values in the respective columns by their indices starting with `0` for the first column (in your case `A`)

Sample:

```js
function updateCar1() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let range = ss.getRange("A2:D61");
  let values = range.getValues();
  let town = ss.getRange("cars!B2").getValue();
  
  for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
    if(values[i][1] == town && values[i][3] =="No" && values[i][2] =="Yes"){
      //do something 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: - Thank you very much. So now I just need to put the data into the desired range?

-     ss.getRange("cars!D2:D10").values.update(USER_ENTERED);

- I get an error:
 
- TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined
updateCar1 @ Code.gs:9

Comment: I don't know what `USER_ENTERED` is, but a method called `values.update` does not exist in Apps Script. Check the [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet) for existing methods.

Comment: So I made something like this:

function updateCar1() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let range = ss.getRange("A2:D61");
  let values = range.getValues();
  let town = ss.getRange("cars!B2").getValue();
  
  for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
    if(values[i][1] == town && values[i][3] =="No" && values[i][2] =="Yes"){
      ss.getRange("D2:D10").setValues(values);
    }
  }
}

but it returns an error "Exception: The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. The data has 60 but the range has 9."